# RestAssured Response is overriden

Tags: java, rest, automation, rest-assured

I am trying to Get multiple URI's using RestAPI programming.
All the GET Requests need Basic Authorization

I have used a BaseClass where I define RequestSpecification as shown below (To avoid Authorization code every time a Test is Run)

BaseClass.java :

```
 RequestSpecification basicAuth=RestAssured.given().accept("text/html").auth().preemptive().basic("username","password");
```

Inherited above Class and used "basicAuth" parameter in the class with my Test methods.

```
  public class Tests extends BaseClass
    {
        @Test(priority=1)
        public void test01() throws IOException
        {
           response=basicAuth.when().get("URL1");
           Assert.assertEquals(200,response.getStatusCode());
        }

          @Test(priority=2)
            public void test02() throws IOException
            {
             response=basicAuth.when().get("URL2");
               Assert.assertEquals(200,response.getStatusCode());
          }}
```

Problem here is both the tests return same Response (test01's response) though the URI's are different . 
Running  test02 alone skipping test01 gives Expected Response.

Workaround is to define two RequestSpecification parameters and Send requests. 
Is there a way where I can clear previous GET Response and send Request again using basicAuth parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to break your call into 2 calls:
1. Add a beforeMethod() function call in which you should call your auth function which is in BaseClass.java and this should return you an object(client) which later you can use in your test class.
2. In each test class, use the client object and make a call to a specific URL. Since each time a before method will be called there is a new client object will be created.
So, ideally your second call will make a call using the auth client and passing the URL object as a parameter.